# serve two docker upstreams in nginx in the same time

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I have a docker architecture consisting of an nginx reverse proxy, a rails app and an instance of the swagger-ui image that I serve on a different container.

My setup in docker-compose is as follows:

```
web:
  restart: always
  ...

swagger-ui:
  image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
  ports: 
    - '8080:8080'
  ...
```

and my nginx conf file as follows:

```
upstream web-app {
          server web:80 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    upstream swagger-ui {
          server swagger-ui:8080 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      server_name www.servername.de servername.de;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
          listen 443 ssl;
          listen [::]:443 ssl;
          server_name servername.de;
          ssl on;
          ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/cert.key;
          ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;


          location /swagger {
            proxy_pass http://swagger-ui;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          }


          location / {
            proxy_pass http://web-app;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

          }
```

everything works well with the rails app;
I can access it through the 443 port with no issue.

My problem is that I would like to also access the /swagger/ path in the same way, but this time access the swagger-ui instance running in the swagger container - what I have been trying so far doesn't seem to work properly, as I get a 404 - I was wondering if maybe I'm missing something to make both of them work in the same time?

If I temporarily set the swagger location to / and comment out the web-app proxy, it points correctly to my swagger-ui container...

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem should be fixed with rewrite!

Now you try to load url like http://swagger-ui:8080/swagger

So you should add to your location this:

```
rewrite    /swagger/(.*) /$1 break;
```

It removes /swagger from your path and should load what you need.